# How to read an individual items of an array in bash for loop

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, jq

I have a code snippet below

```
values=(addressSearchBaseUrl addressSearchSubscriptionKey cacheUrl calendarApiUrl checkoutBffApiUrl cpCode)

az_create_options=()

for ptr in "${values[@]}"
do
result=$(
az pipelines variable-group list --group-name "${Variable Group ${reference_env}" | jq '.[0].variables.'${ptr}'.value'
)


if [[ "$ptr" = "calendarApiUrl" ]]
then
echo "INF: Updating $ptr with new value"
result="https://noname-api.platform.test.com.au/marketing/calendar/v1/AvailableDates/market1/"
insertString=";rev=${target_env}"
lookingfor="v1"
result=$(echo $result| sed s/"${lookingfor}"/"${insertString}"/g)
echo $result
fi

az_create_options+=("$result" )
done

declare -p az_create_options

values=(addressSearchBaseUrl addressSearchSubscriptionKey cacheUrl calendarApiUrl checkoutBffApiUrl cpCode)

for ptr in "${values[@]}"
do
az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id 1543 --name "${ptr} --value "${az_create_options[0]}" First element read and value updated
az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id 1543 --name "${ptr} --value "${az_create_options[0]}" Second element read and value updated
done
```

The last for loop is where I need help as I do not know how to refer an array in bash.I need to point to individual items of az_create_options as they have to go 1:1.

Forgive me for my bash incompetency, but, I am here to learn.

Comment: but you are already using it with `${arr[0]}`. Could you elaborate a bit

Comment: during the loop you `ptr` is the value of the index. `az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id 1543 --name "${ptr} --value "$ptr"`

Comment: No, value is fetched and stored in az_create_options array.

Comment: It needs in a loop Sir. for i in <array> I have to get the value from another array. Got it?

Comment: you can use a counter variable that you can initialize outside the loop and then when you run the loop access the value from the other array using the counter as an index and then increment the counter before the loop ends

Comment: There is a closing curly break missing here: `"${Variable Group ${reference_env}"`

Comment: You might consider making `az_create_options` an associative array, with the values in `values` used as the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the array *indices*:

```sh
for ((i = 0; i < ${#values[@]}; i++)); do
  value=${values[i]}
  option=${az_create_options[i]}

  echo "value => $value; option => $option"
done
```

Comment: Thank you to Glenn and Abhishek. Both of your answers are right. I have accepted the one form Glenn as it is more compact.

Comment: Note that this will break with sparse arrays. To really iterate over array indices you need to use: `for i in "${!values[@]}"; do`…

Answer (score 1):

```
ctr=0
for ptr in "${values[@]}"
do
    az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id 1543 --name "${ptr}" --value "${az_create_options[$ctr]}" #First element read and value updated
    az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id 1543 --name "${ptr}" --value "${az_create_options[$ctr]}" #Second element read and value updated
    ctr=$((ctr+1))
done
```